# Storing 64 bits timestamps in Javascript 53 bits Number format

Tags: javascript, numbers, timestamp, precision

### Background

I am decoding data from a Buffer that has a timestamp encoded in 8 bytes ( 64 bits ).

Normally this wouldn't be a problem, except that `Number` in JavaScript only works with numbers up to 53 bits - then it loses precision.

### Problem

This means that if I store that timestamp in a JavaScript Number, I will loose precision as the Number format is not big enough to store the timestamp.

Since this is an application that needs time precision *at least* up to the second, I am not keen on losing *too much* precision.

### Example

To prove my point, here is an Hex String that is a timestamp 64 bits long. If you are using Node.js you can test it like the following:

```
//a small timestamp from our current time in history
var buf = Buffer.from(
    "162F1544EA81242A",
    "hex"
);

buf.readUInt( 0, 6 ); // lost 2 bytes of precision here!
```

This timestamp should give some value in the future:

> Assuming that this timestamp is in microseconds (1/1,000,000 second):
>   GMT: Thursday, August 27, 2020 9:16:18.476 AM Your time zone:
>   Thursday, August 27, 2020 11:16:18.476 AM GMT+02:00 DST

### Question

- How much precision ( in milliseconds ) will a 64 bits timestamp loose if it is saved in the JavaScript 53 bits Number format?

Comment: Javascript stores date's as a number, and it has ms accuracy,.  So 1 second accuracy should not cause you any problems.  IOW: you should loose 0 milliseconds..

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how Number behaves when given a BigInt ( 64 bits long ). BigInts will be added to JS in the near future, but until then I have no solution.

Comment: Can you give an example buffer, and an example output expected. ?

Comment: Added an example to the question !

Comment: And what date and time is that meant to represent, your original version was a totally valid Javascript date, why did you change?  eg.  your previous version `new Date(0x162F1544EA8)` was fine.

Comment: [Asking for down vote reasons is not constructive in this passive aggressive manner is not constructive.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/37090) the only explination/reason for a down vote you should ever expect is available if you hover over the down vote arrow.

Comment: I changed because I wanted to fill all the bits and leave none with 0. Somehow I fear people will simply copy paste the example and immediately downvote me because this specific test would cause no loss in precision ( it had too many zeroes on the left ).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript's `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER`, 2^53 - 1, has a value of 9,007,199,254,740,991. Realize, however, that there's a sign bit in addition to the 53 bits of integer precision, so if your timestamps are signed, you can take advantage of that too.

Let's stick with the idea of this being a timestamp in microseconds, not milliseconds. How much of a time range does 53 bits plus a sign bit cover? Convert 9,007,199,254,740,991 microseconds to years and you get roughly ±285 years. For most purposes that should be good enough.

If you choose to drop some resolution and convert to milliseconds, then your time stamps can cover a range of ±285,000 years.

Answer (score 0):

This is clearly easy to test, JavaScript uses exactly 64 bit floating point to store numbers, floating point means precision decreases as number increases, so pick the maximum possible value that you need and try subtracting 1, 2, 3, etc. until you get a different value, that way you have exactly the minimum time difference that can be registered.

Comment: timestamps are not floating point. They are ints. That's why this is a problem, because javascript can only story timestamps up to 53 bits long.

Comment: there is no long in javascript, it simply converts to float and 53 bits are just the part which is stored exactly.